# Can I disable max-page-size completely for pagination in micronaut?

Tags: configuration, pagination, micronaut

In my configuration file, when I remove the `max-page-size` parameter, Micronaut still uses a default value of 100 (as one would expect after reading [the documentation](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/3.4.0/api/io/micronaut/data/runtime/config/DataConfiguration.PageableConfiguration.html)). However, **I would like to remove this limitation completely**. The most obvious way would be just setting the value to a absurdly high number like 9999999999 but I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

I haven't found any special configuration to tell micronaut to do so, so I am considering extending the Pageable class to see if overriding some getter I can bypass the default limit.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best workaround I've found is setting the limit to the special YAML value for infinity: `.inf`.

```yaml
micronaut:
  data:
    pageable:
      max-page-size: .inf
```

This way the value parsed by Micronaut is the maximum int value `2147483647`, which is more than enough to consider the page size unlimited.